# Second highest value

Tags: google-sheets

I know how to use MAX(A1:A30) to get the highest value in the cell range A1 to A30.

But how do I get the second or third highest value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following formula, will allow you to choose the highest value you want:

```
=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A30),1,FALSE),1,0)
```

The formula explained from the inside out:

- The `SORT` function will sort the range `DESCENDING` via the `FALSE`
  statement (high to low). The `1` indicates the first column.
- The `UNIQUE` function will exclude any duplicates
- The `INDEX` function will allow you to select the order you want: `1` for the first, `2` for the second....and so on.

I was about to write a script and found out that the problem can be resolved by good old formulas !!

Answer (score 13):

Try looking for the [`SMALL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094050) and [`LARGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094008) formula.

I'd use:

```
=LARGE(UNIQUE(A1:A30);2)
```

[`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198) to pick and look only for the different values in the range.
The number `2` is for the 2nd largest number.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but if anyone wants to get the 2nd Highest Value **treating ties as the same rank** then the following will work:

```
=LARGE(A1:A30,COUNTIF(A1:A30,MAX(A1:A30))+1)
```